# Python - rock paper scissors, problem with if statements

Tags: python

I believe the problem is with my indentation, if me and computer both choose scissors it prints You lose - paper beats rock!. but I could be wrong, can anyone give me some assistance please. i think issue is with the dictating the winner section.

```
# Random function import
import random

# Game rules
print('Rock(1), Paper(2), Scissors(3)')
print('')

# Assigning player variable and allowing user input
player = int(input('Enter your selection!'))

# If statements assigning player selection
if player == 1:
    print('You chose Rock')
elif player == 2:
    print('You chose Paper')
else:
    print('You chose Scissors')
     
#Declaring the computer variable and allowing it to access random function
computer = random.randint(1,3)

# if statements assigning computers selection
if computer == 1:
    print('computer chose Rock')
elif player == 2:
    print('computer chose Paper')
else:
    print('computer chose Scissors')


# If statements dictating the winner
if player == 1 and computer == 2:
    print('Paper covers rock - You lose!.')
elif player == 1 and computer == 3:
    print('Rock crushes scissors - You win!.')    
elif player == 2 and computer == 1:
    print('Paper covers rock - You win!.')
elif player == 2 and computer == 3:
    print('Scissors cut paper - You lose!.')
elif player == 3 and computer == 1:
    print('Rock crushes scissors - You lose!.') 
elif player == 3 and computer == 2:enter code here
    print('Scissors cut paper - You Win!.')
elif player == computer:
    print('Game is a draw!')
```

Comment: How can this code ever output "paper beats rock"? That's not in the code.

Comment: @mkrieger1 what do you mean? He has player 1 comp 2 is paper beats rock and player 2 comp 1 paper beats rock?

Comment: line 24 of your code must be this `elif computer == 2:`

Comment: `paper covers rock` is his way of saying `paper beats rock`... I am unsure what your comment is?

Comment: @mkrieger1 what are you talking about? His code is perfectly fine as to the logic of the game. He just needed to change line 24 as ImThePeak and captain-nemo-10994 stated.

Comment: There's no indentation problem, you just have a typo in one of the `if` statements.

Answer (score 1):

In your if statements that assign the computer's selection, the second statement says, `elif player == 2`. Pretty sure that should be `elif computer == 2`.

You've also got at trailing "enter code here" three lines up from the bottom.

I ran the code on my machine and can't replicate the problem you're describing.

Comment: `enter code here` is a Stack Overflow placeholder, so it's a copying error.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use some magic of python like list to make the code more readable and easy to debug I respect your try but you should read more about python data structure
study this code :

```
import random
while True:
    choices = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissor']
    computer = random.choice(choices)
    player = None
    while player not in choices:
        player = input('rock , paper, sicissor?:')

    if player == computer:
        print('computer:', computer)
        print('player:', player)
        print('Tie!')
    elif player == 'rock':
        if computer == 'paper':
            print('computer:', computer)
            print('player:', player)
            print('you lose!')
        if computer == 'scissor':
            print('computer:', computer)
            print('player:', player)
            print('you win!')
    elif player == 'scissor':
        if computer == 'rock':
            print('computer:', computer)
            print('player:', player)
            print('you lose!')
        if computer == 'paper':
            print('computer:', computer)
            print('player:', player)
            print('you win!')
    elif player == 'paper':
        if computer == 'scissor':
            print('computer:', computer)
            print('player:', player)
            print('you lose!')
        if computer == 'rock':
            print('computer:', computer)
            print('player:', player)
            print('you win!')

    play_again = input('Play again? (yes/no):').lower()

    if play_again != 'yes':
        break
print('Bye')
```